# How to get GWTUpload SingleUploader to replace the previously selected image

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am using GWTUpload SingleUploader to select and display a photograph. If I select a photograph and then change my mind and select a different photograph the next photograph is displayed next to the first. How do I get it to replace the previous photograph.

Regards,

Glyn

```
package org.AwardTracker.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.ServiceDefTarget;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasHorizontalAlignment;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ListBox;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat;

import gwtupload.client.IFileInput;
import gwtupload.client.IFileInput.FileInputType;
import gwtupload.client.IUploadStatus.Status;
import gwtupload.client.IUploader;
import gwtupload.client.IUploader.UploadedInfo;
import gwtupload.client.MultiUploader;
import gwtupload.client.PreloadedImage;
import gwtupload.client.PreloadedImage.OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler;
import gwtupload.client.SingleUploader;

//import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.String;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FileUpload;
import com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox.DefaultFormat;

public class EditYouthMemberView extends Composite {

private DBConnectionAsync rpc;
private TextBox textBoxFirstName;
private TextBox textBoxScoutNumber;
private ListBox listBoxSection;
private ListBox listBoxPack;
private TextBox textBoxSurname;
private DateBox dateBoxArchived;
private DateBox dateBoxPackIn;
private DateBox dateBoxPackOut;
private DateBox dateBoxDOB;
// A panel where the thumbnails of upload images will be shown
//final FlowPanel panelImages = new FlowPanel();
final HorizontalPanel panelImages = new HorizontalPanel();


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public EditYouthMemberView(final NavHandler navHandler) {       

    final java.util.Date todays_date = new java.util.Date();

    rpc = (DBConnectionAsync) GWT.create(DBConnection.class);
    ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) rpc;
    String moduleRelativeURL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "MySQLConnection";
    target.setServiceEntryPoint(moduleRelativeURL);

    VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    verticalPanel.setStyleName("gwt-Banner");
    initWidget(verticalPanel);

    HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    horizontalPanel.setStyleName("gwt-Banner");
    verticalPanel.add(horizontalPanel);
    horizontalPanel.setWidth("246px");

    Label lblHome = new Label("Home");
    lblHome.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        }
    });
    horizontalPanel.add(lblHome);
    lblHome.setWidth("46px");

    Label lblEditAwards = new Label("Edit Awards");
    lblEditAwards.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        }
    });
    horizontalPanel.add(lblEditAwards);
    lblEditAwards.setWidth("85px");

    Label lblListAll = new Label("List all Cub Scouts");
    lblListAll.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        }
    });
    horizontalPanel.add(lblListAll);
    lblListAll.setWidth("130px");

    Label lblAccountUpdate = new Label("Account Update");
    lblAccountUpdate.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        }
    });
    horizontalPanel.add(lblAccountUpdate);
    lblAccountUpdate.setWidth("104px");

    FlexTable flexTable_1 = new FlexTable();
    verticalPanel.add(flexTable_1);

    Label lblSurname = new Label("Surname");
    lblSurname.setWordWrap(false);
    lblSurname.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
    lblSurname.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable_1.setWidget(0, 2, lblSurname);

    Label lblFirstName = new Label("First Name");
    lblFirstName.setWordWrap(false);
    lblFirstName.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
    lblFirstName.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable_1.setWidget(0, 3, lblFirstName);

    textBoxSurname = new TextBox();
    flexTable_1.setWidget(1, 1, textBoxSurname);

    textBoxFirstName = new TextBox();
    flexTable_1.setWidget(1, 2, textBoxFirstName);      

    Label lblLookForPhotograph = new Label("Look for photograph:");
    lblLookForPhotograph.setWordWrap(false);
    lblLookForPhotograph.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
    lblLookForPhotograph.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable_1.setWidget(2, 1, lblLookForPhotograph);
    flexTable_1.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(2, 1, 3);

    // Attach the image viewer to the document
    flexTable_1.setWidget(0, 0, panelImages);
    panelImages.setSize("120", "120");
    flexTable_1.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(0, 0, 4);
    panelImages.clear();

    // Create a new uploader panel and attach it to a document
    //final SingleUploader defaultUploader = new SingleUploader(IFileInput.FileInputType.LABEL, null);
    final SingleUploader defaultUploader = new SingleUploader();
    defaultUploader.setAutoSubmit(false);
    defaultUploader.setValidExtensions("jpg");
    defaultUploader.setEnabled(true);

    // Add a finish handler which will load the image once the upload finishes
    defaultUploader.addOnFinishUploadHandler(onFinishUploaderHandler);
    defaultUploader.getFileInput().getWidget().setStyleName("customButton"); 
    defaultUploader.getFileInput().getWidget().setSize("159px", "27px");
    defaultUploader.avoidRepeatFiles(true);
    //defaultUploader.setServletPath(defaultUploader.getServletPath() + "?caseId=" + caseObj.getId().toString());

    flexTable_1.setWidget(3, 1, defaultUploader);
    flexTable_1.getFlexCellFormatter().setRowSpan(3, 1, 3);

    FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable();
    verticalPanel.add(flexTable);

    Label lblDOB = new Label("Date of Birth:");
    lblDOB.setWordWrap(false);
    lblDOB.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(0, 0, lblDOB);
    lblDOB.setDirectionEstimator(false);
    lblDOB.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    lblDOB.setSize("110px", "16px");

    dateBoxDOB = new DateBox();
    dateBoxDOB.setFormat(new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")));
    flexTable.setWidget(0, 1, dateBoxDOB);
    dateBoxDOB.getDatePicker();

    Label lblSection = new Label("Section:");
    lblSection.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    lblSection.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(0, 2, lblSection);

    listBoxSection = new ListBox();
    listBoxSection.addItem("Cubs");
    flexTable.setWidget(0, 3, listBoxSection);
    listBoxSection.setVisibleItemCount(1);

    Label lblScoutNumber = new Label("Scout Number:");
    lblScoutNumber.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    lblScoutNumber.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(1, 0, lblScoutNumber);
    lblScoutNumber.setDirectionEstimator(false);
    lblScoutNumber.setSize("110px", "16px");

    textBoxScoutNumber = new TextBox();
    flexTable.setWidget(1, 1, textBoxScoutNumber);

    Label lblPack = new Label("Pack:");
    lblPack.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    lblPack.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(1, 2, lblPack);

    listBoxPack = new ListBox();
    listBoxPack.addItem("Explorer");
    listBoxPack.addItem("Pioneer");
    flexTable.setWidget(1, 3, listBoxPack);
    listBoxPack.setVisibleItemCount(1);

    Label lblDateArchived = new Label("Date Archived:");
    lblDateArchived.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    lblDateArchived.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(2, 0, lblDateArchived);
    lblDateArchived.setSize("110px", "16px");

    dateBoxArchived = new DateBox();
    dateBoxArchived.setFormat(new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")));
    flexTable.setWidget(2, 1, dateBoxArchived);
    dateBoxArchived.getDatePicker();

    Label lblIn_1 = new Label("In:");
    lblIn_1.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    lblIn_1.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(2, 2, lblIn_1);

    dateBoxPackIn = new DateBox();
    dateBoxPackIn.setFormat(new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFullDateFormat()));
    flexTable.setWidget(2, 3, dateBoxPackIn);
    dateBoxPackIn.getDatePicker();

    Label lblNewLabel_3 = new Label("Out:");
    lblNewLabel_3.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
    flexTable.setWidget(2, 4, lblNewLabel_3);

    dateBoxPackOut = new DateBox();
    dateBoxPackOut.setFormat(new DefaultFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")));
    dateBoxPackOut.getDatePicker();

    flexTable.setWidget(2, 5, dateBoxPackOut);

    Button btnAdd = new Button("Add");
    btnAdd.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Integer tracker = 0;
            if (textBoxSurname.getText().length() == 0) {
                tracker = tracker + 1; 
            }
            if (textBoxFirstName.getText().length() == 0) {
                tracker = tracker + 2; 
            }
            //TO DO
            // How do I check that a picture has been selected?
            // if (panelImages.getFilename().length() == 0) {
            //  tracker = tracker + 4; 
            // }
            if (dateBoxDOB.toString().length() == 0) {
                tracker = tracker + 8; 
            }
            if (dateBoxPackIn.toString().length() == 0) {
                tracker = tracker + 16; 
            }

            if (tracker == 1) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname.");
            }
            if (tracker == 2) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a First Name.");
            }
            if (tracker == 3) {
                Window.alert("Please enter Surname and First Name");
            }
            if (tracker == 4) {
                Window.alert("Please select a photograph.");
            }
            if (tracker == 5) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname and select a photograph.");
            }
            if (tracker == 6) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a FirstName and select a photograph.");
            }
            if (tracker == 7) {
                Window.alert("Please enter Surname, First Name and select a photograph");
            }
            if (tracker == 8) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 9) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname and DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 10) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a First Name and DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 11) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname, First Name and DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 12) {
                Window.alert("Please select a photograph and enter a BOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 13) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname, select a photograph and enter a DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 14) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a FirstName, select a photograph and enter a DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 15) {
                Window.alert("Please enter Surname, First Name, select a photograph and enter a DOB");
            }
            if (tracker == 16) {
                Window.alert("Please enter date joined Pack");
            }

            if (tracker == 17) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname and date joined Pack.");
            }
            if (tracker == 18) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a First Name and date joined Pack.");
            }
            if (tracker == 19) {
                Window.alert("Please enter Surname, First Name and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 20) {
                Window.alert("Please select a photograph and enter date joined Pack.");
            }
            if (tracker == 21) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname, select a photograph and enter date joined Pack.");
            }
            if (tracker == 22) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a First Name, select a photograph and enter date joined Pack.");
            }
            if (tracker == 23) {
                Window.alert("Please enter Surname, First Name, select a photograph and enter date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 24) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a DOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 25) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname, DOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 26) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a First Name, DOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 27) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname, First Name, DOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 28) {
                Window.alert("Please select a photograph, enter a BOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 29) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a Surname, select a photograph, enter a DOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 30) {
                Window.alert("Please enter a FirstName, select a photograph, enter a DOB and date joined Pack");
            }
            if (tracker == 31) {
                Window.alert("Please enter Surname, First Name, select a photograph, enter a DOB and date joined Pack");
            }

            //if (tracker == 0) {
            //  AsyncCallback<YthMmbrSectDtls> callback = new CreationHandler<YthMmbrSectDtls>(null);
            //  rpc.createYouthMember(null, textBoxSurname.getText(), textBoxFirstName.getText(), dateBoxDOB.getValue(), 
            //          fileUpload.getFilename(), dateBoxArchived.getValue(), null, listBoxSection.getItemText(listBoxSection.getSelectedIndex()),
            //          listBoxPack.getItemText(listBoxPack.getSelectedIndex()), dateBoxPackIn.getValue(), 
            //          dateBoxPackOut.getValue(), callback);
            //}

        }

    });
    flexTable.setWidget(3, 0, btnAdd);

    Button btnUpdate = new Button("Update");
    btnUpdate.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        }
    });
    btnUpdate.setText("Update");
    flexTable.setWidget(3, 1, btnUpdate);

    Button btnCancel = new Button("Cancel");
    btnCancel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        }
    });
    btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
    flexTable.setWidget(3, 2, btnCancel);

    Button btnClearPage = new Button("Clear Page");
    btnClearPage.setText("Clear Page");
    btnClearPage.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            textBoxSurname.setText("");
            textBoxFirstName.setText("");
            dateBoxDOB.setValue(null);
            dateBoxPackIn.setValue(todays_date);
            dateBoxPackOut.setValue(null);
            textBoxScoutNumber.setText("");
            dateBoxArchived.setValue(null);
        }
    });
    flexTable.setWidget(3, 3, btnClearPage);
    setStyleName("body");
}

// Load the image in the document and in the case of success attach it to the viewer
private IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler onFinishUploaderHandler = new IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
    public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
        if (uploader.getStatus() == Status.SUCCESS) {
            new PreloadedImage(uploader.fileUrl(), showImage);

            //The server sends useful information to the client by default
            UploadedInfo info = uploader.getServerInfo();
            System.out.println("File name " + info.name);
            System.out.println("File content-type " + info.ctype);
            System.out.println("File size " + info.size);

            // You can send any customised message and parse it
            System.out.println("Server message " + info.message);

        }
    }
};

// Attach an image to the pictures viewer
private OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler showImage = new OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler() {
    public void onLoad(PreloadedImage image) {
        image.setWidth("75px");
        panelImages.add(image);
    }
};

/**
 * Decodes the base64 string into byte array to display image
 * Calls Base64Decode.java
 * @param imageDataString - a {@link java.lang.String}
 * @return byte array
 */
public static byte[] decodeImage(String imageDataString) {
    return Base64Decode.decode(imageDataString);
    }

public IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler getOnFinishUploaderHandler() {
    return onFinishUploaderHandler;
}

public void setOnFinishUploaderHandler(IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler onFinishUploaderHandler) {
    this.onFinishUploaderHandler = onFinishUploaderHandler;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it seems that you only have one image in your `panelImages`, so calling `panelImages.clear()` should work.

If you had more images in your panel, and you wanted to remove the last image added with the uploader, you could just save it in a class variable. Then you can use that variable to remove the next time:

```
private Widget lastImage = null;

private OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler showImage = new OnLoadPreloadedImageHandler() {
  public void onLoad(PreloadedImage image) {
    if (lastImage != null) {
      lastImage.removeFromParent()
    }
    lastImage = image;
    image.setWidth("75px");
    panelImages.add(image);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much once again Manolo. Just to complete this. This will allow you to select a different picture each time. It will not allow you to reselect and display any picture you have already selected (e.g., select John.jpg, then select five other pictures, clearing the one before each time, and then you decide John.jpg was the one you wanted so you resect it. The current photo will clear ant 5he path to John.jpg will display but the photograph will not display). The way round this is to set defaultUploader.avoidRepeatFiles(true); to defaultUploader.avoidRepeatFiles(false);. Thanks Glyn

Comment: Hi Manlo, you would not have an answer to my other question on how to display the photo and path would you? Currently once the photo is displayed the path disappears. Regards,  Glyn

Comment: in order to change each file, you need different single uploaders for each file. Another option which does NOT work currently, but will do soon is that you would be able to add a click-handler anywhere (in your case to each image) to fire the opening of the upload browser.

Comment: Hi Manolo, I am not sure that I understand your last post above. However, this now works and I will leave further discussions on my other post there; which you have already responded to. Many thanks, Glyn.